# How to scrape genecards summaries with R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I want to scrape genecards.com. The function `paths_allowed()` from the `robotstxt` package says that the information about a given gene is allowed to be scraped. My example was: https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=TOP1
I want to extract the summaries section, so namely from: "Entrez Gene Summary for TOP1 Gene" to "Gene Wiki entry for TOP1 Gene". Either the whole section at once or one summary after another.
I tried it with one section after another with the class tag ".list-unstyled"
My process this far:

```
genes <- c("TOP1")

paths_allowed(paths = "https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=TOP1")
base <- xml2::read_html(paste0(base_genecards, genes[1]))
base %>% html_nodes(".list-unstyled") # refer to the in the hierarchy lowest class
```

This gives the result of

```
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

I know that I have to use `html_text()` afterwards, but I don't get this far, because I don't get any query to work on this page. I tried it on imdb and it works.
I struggle to get the text of the summaries into R. Where is my error?
Thanks

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__, __scraping__, __scraped__ and __scraper__ not scrap, scrapping, scrapped or scrapper. 'To scrap' means to throw away like rubbish :-(

Answer (score 1):

To all, who find this: Seems like genecards is protected by incapsula and this is to protect this website from to be scraped.